# Multiple URL's based on category for one post

Tags: categories, permalinks, pages, url-rewriting

I have a rather odd question, I think.

I have some post. This post (not all of them) will get a `category`, when I give this category to it in the admin area. But... while I am using the same post, I don't want the content to be the same! So it's actually adding the category to the `permalink` and transforming it to another page with different contents. What I care about, is the URL in this case.

So this category will be the parent, actually. I want to achieve this:

> http://mywebsite.com/this-is-my-post
>
> http://mywebsite.com/category-name/this-is-my-post

I want to be able to access both pages!

**As I said: although the first post is being used and transformed, I want to have a different content / template on it.**

So I was thinking about it and thought: well, why not make a page? But in that case, I would have to do that manually and add like thousands of pages and that's just crazy.

Can someone help me please? I'd like to this in a way where I can avoid SEO penalties.

**PS:** I am using the postname permalink structure and I want to retain that.